# ScriptTimeoutError while testing angular material dropdown e2e

Tags: testing, jasmine, protractor, angular-e2e

I have this test case

```
it("should have list", async () => {
    // wait until list populated
    browser.wait(protractor.until.elementLocated(by.css(COMPONENT_CSS.ITEM)));

    console.log("First...............");
    try {
        await componentPage.toggleDD();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("err", err);
    }
    console.log("Second...............");
    const count = await componentPage.getCount();
    console.log("count", count);
    expect(count).toBe(this.COUNT);
    await componentPage.toggleDD();
});
```

and here is toggleDD

```
async toggleDD(): Promise<any> {
    const _dropdown = await element(by.id(this.CSS.DD_ID));
    await _dropdown.click();
}
```

but this shows

```
err ScriptTimeoutError: script timeout
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.135)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868b4cc0aa7e8149519690b6f6949e110a8-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#310}),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (E:\PROJECTS\NewProject\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (E:\PROJECTS\NewProject\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at E:\PROJECTS\NewProject\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
From: Task: Protractor.waitForAngular() - Locator: By(css selector, *[id="my-dropdown"])
```

and fails the test case, I have tried putting `await` before `browser.wait`, tried `by.xpath`, `by.id`, `by.css` to get dropdown.

I tried it in debug mode, elements are present on DOM but somehow it is not getting the element.

Checked other element to get for each element it is showing

```
- Failed: script timeout
    (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.135)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868b4cc0aa7e8149519690b6f6949e110a8-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#310}),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

I tried

```
<div id="dummyId">Hello</div>
```

with this div by

```
const _divText = await element(by.id("dummyId")).getText();
```

even for this I am getting **scripttimeout err**

**More Info**

Here is `beforeAll`

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    componentPage = new HomePage();
    helperService = new HelperService();

    COMPONENT_CSS = componentPage.CSS;
    await helperService.navigate(helperService.PAGE_URL.HOME);
    try {
        await helperService.skipIntro();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Intro element not found");
    }
    // browser.waitForAngular();
});
```

and **protractor.conf.js**

```
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

const { SpecReporter } = require("jasmine-spec-reporter");

exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 50000,
    specs: [
        "./src/login/login.component.e2e-spec.ts",
        "./src/home/home.component.e2e-spec.ts",
    ],
    capabilities: {
        "browserName": "chrome"
    },
    directConnect: true,
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:4200/",
    framework: "jasmine",
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 1000000,
        print: function () {
        }
    },
    onPrepare() {
        require("ts-node").register({
            project: require("path").join(__dirname, "./tsconfig.e2e.json")
        });
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    }
};
```

Comment: First glance, I am assuming this is async / await and not the control flow. `browser.wait` should be awaited.  I'm guessing this is why the element is not visible on the screen when `toggleDD` has been called. Give it a try. If you get stuck, I could also write an answer

Comment: @cnishina, tried that not working

Comment: @cnishina not able to produce in the demo project, though updated the question, included protractor.conf.js and beforeAll function, any other way arround to look into it

Comment: Sorry this has taken me a while to respond back. What kind of dropdown is it? Is it an angular material dropdown like https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview ?

Comment: @cnishina yes angular material, tried to reproduce in demo project, but i am not able to..

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error, it appears that the element is not displayed before you want to interact with it. `until.elementLocated` appears to call into `findElements` and return the first element.

See https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.js#L241

This means that it will return it if it is in the DOM but doesn't mean that it will be displayed or enabled to click. The `isDisplayed` call explicitly checks that the element is displayed.

See https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js#L2296

Maybe instead do something like this?

```
it("should have list", async () => {
  // wait until list populated
  await browser.wait(async () => {
    return element(by.css(COMPONENT_CSS.ITEM)).isDisplayed();
  }, 10000);  // wait 10 seconds, make sure your protractor suite does not time out.
```

Comment: will try and let you know

Comment: not working, same kind of code is working for login page, before home page i test login page that works fine. tried isDisplayed not working, even static div with some id, not able to find that, used debugger , when the control reach to debugger evverything is on dom

Comment: Do you have this to try out on GitHub? I think that might be the easiest way to help debug this.

Comment: kind of private project, may you can try taking remote or on skype by screen sharing

Comment: Could you just create an example angular app with a material drop down menu that can duplicate your error?